# "Failed to open stream" error with Laravel running tests with sqlite in memory

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, phpunit

I'm trying to run the default Laravel 5.5 unit test:

```
phpunit --filter testBasicTest
```

The relevant part of my `phpunit.xml` file is:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
</php>
```

I get this error:

> ErrorException: file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\path_to_app\database\:memory:): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I've tried `artisan config:clear`, but get the same error.

Comment: is your file path correct or exist the file name???

Comment: Show your `sqlite` connection config.

Comment: @Camilo The `phpunit.xml` config overrides the `sqlite` connection config. It's using the `:memory:` database connection.

Comment: Just to be sure, do `artisan config:clear` and then try again.

Comment: @Camilo Sorry - should have mentioned I've already done that. Same error.

Comment: Did you try setting the DB_DEFAULT env-variable in the phpunit.xml? And are you using the DatabaseMigrations-Trait?

Comment: I shouldn't need to set `DB_DEFAULT`. I am using the `RefreshDatabase` trait, which replaces `DatabaseMigrations` in 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add testing connection to `config/database.php`:

```
'connections' => [

    'testing' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    ....
```